# How to make a winsock listen on a particular port?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, ports

This must be really obvious, but how do I make a winsock listen to a specific port (recieve data?) I cannot find a method that lets me do so!

Sorry that this is probably so obvious.

I am trying to make a chat application, which is obviously running in a server/client setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737550%28VS.85%29.aspx) the socket, and then [listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737526%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737526%28VS.85%29.aspx) connections. Described in more detail in [Getting started with WinSock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545%28VS.85%29.aspx). There's also a [good guide](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) to the BSD sockets, which you should read too.

For .NET, you probably want [System.Net.Sockets.Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) (and it's Bind/Listen/Accept/Send/Receive methods) instead of native WinSock, but the concepts are the same, so I'll leave all links.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is in vb.net by the way.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be tagged as WinSock question. I've added .NET sockets to answer.

Answer (score 1):

When using TCP sockets you bind, listen and accept and eventually recv. You can find some tutorials over [here](http://www.win32developer.com/tutorial.shtm) or check out the official MSDN documentation.

The winsock API is based on UNIX' BSD sockets; so they are very very similar.  You might want to look into that. A book that I've recently is [UNIX Network Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139498761) by Richard Stevens and he explains pretty much everything there is to know about sockets.

You might also consider running your sockets in a separate thread to improve readability and performance.

Edit: As for listening on a specific port; this is the sin.port parameter of your SOCKADDR_IN struct.